# Notice: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am getting an error when posting via ajax to a csv file via php.

```
<?php
$list = array ($_POST["array"]);
$fp = fopen('array.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, $list);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

My array i am trying to post

```
["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 99]
```

The response:

**Notice**:  Array to string conversion in **C:\xampp\htdocs\snx\assets\www\write.php** on line **4**

My Ajax post;

```
/* Array */
var defaultArray = new Array();
var localArray = new Array();
var serverArray = new Array();

/* Default Values */
defaultArray[0] = "0";
defaultArray[1] = "0";
defaultArray[2] = "0";
defaultArray[3] = "0";
defaultArray[4] = "0";
defaultArray[5] = "0";
defaultArray[6] = "0";
defaultArray[7] = "0";
defaultArray.push(99);

/* Write Array [1st Load] */
$.post("write.php", { 'array': defaultArray });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$list = array ($_POST["array"]);
```

If `$_POST['array']` is already an array, `Array($_POST['array'])` makes an array of [one] arrays of strings.

If you write `print_r($list)`, you will see something like this:

```
Array(0 =>
 Array(
   0 => "0",
   1 => "0",
   2 => "0",
   3 => "0",
   4 => "0",
   5 => "0",
   6 => "0",
   7 => "0",
   8 => 99
 )
)
```

To use the original array of strings, you probably just want:

```
$list = $_POST["array"];
```

Now, when you write `print_r($list)`, you'll see the expected:

```
Array(
   0 => "0",
   1 => "0",
   2 => "0",
   3 => "0",
   4 => "0",
   5 => "0",
   6 => "0",
   7 => "0",
   8 => 99
)
```

---

BTW, use **only** `.push` for adding items to Javascript arrays, which you should instantiate like `= []`, not `= new Array()`.

Comment: God i love this site, Praise the lord for Stackoverflow.com

Comment: Hallelujah! Let us praise the goddess of the fallen children!